# Logical OR does not work properly in the while loop

Tags: java, while-loop, conditional-statements, logical-operators

The problem is that, the first condition in the while loop does not get executed at all even if its true. If i remove the Logical OR from the while loop and just write the first condition (`selection.compareToIgnoreCase("O") >0`) it works fine. But if there are two conditions with Logical OR, it does not work.

I've tried using `equals()`, I've also tried to negate the logic using 
`while(!selection.equals("O") || !selection.equals("E"))`. The second condition works fine but the first does not work at all.

```
public class OddsOrEvens {
public  static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println("Let’s play a game called \"Odds and Evens\"");
    System.out.println("Whats your name ? ");
    String name = sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Hi "+ name +", which do you choose? (O)dds or (E)vens?");
    String selection = sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println("selection: " + selection);

    while (selection.compareToIgnoreCase("O") >0 || selection.compareToIgnoreCase("E") >0){
        System.out.println("Please enter the correct choice. Select 'O' for odds or 'E' for evens");
        selection = sc.next();
    }

    if(selection.equalsIgnoreCase("O")){
        System.out.println(name + " has picked Odds! The computer will be evens.");
    }else if (selection.equalsIgnoreCase("E")){
        System.out.println(name + " has picked Evens! The computer will be Odds.");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: You should really write out a truth table of your conditions.

Comment: have you tried debugging?

Comment: `selection.compareToIgnoreCase("O") >0` is checking if the selection is **greater** than `"O". Try `selection.compareToIgnoreCase("O") == 0`.

Comment: Yes I have tried debugging, the values in variable(Selection) are always as intended but the loop does not work properly.

Comment: @oldCurmdgeon If i change it to == then it will go in an infinite loop.

Comment: @cargeh Tried using equals() also. But the first condition never works. But the second one does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is for *not to hold for two cases*, one needs `!... && ! ...` An OR `||` would have the effect of being always true, as at least one of the cases is false. Alternatively `!(... || ...)`.

```
while (!selection.equalsIgnoreCase("O") && !selection.equalsIgnoreCase("E")) {
```

---

Let's simplify:

```
!(n == 1) || !(n == 2)       // WRONG
  n != 1  ||   n != 2        // WRONG
```

will always be true, as either n == 1 is false or n == 2 is false: at most one choice can be true, falsifying the others. So on at least on side is !false, true, so the entire expression is true.

```
!(n == 1) && !(n == 2)       // GOOD
  n != 1  &&   n != 2        // GOOD
```

The mental mistake is that the linguistic OR mostly means EXCLUSIVE OR.

Possible would have been the equivalent:

```
!(n == 1 || n == 2)      <=>      n != 1 && n != 2   [De Morgan's law]
```

Comment: I understand it much better now. Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 2):

Your string comparison is not correct. Compareto returns -1/0/1 for less/equal/greater.

A clearer way to do this is to use `toUppercase().equals(...`.

```
    while (!selection.toUpperCase().equals("O") && !selection.toUpperCase().equals("E")){
```